# AngularJS: How to fix scope overwriting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi i have in my controller such functions:

```
var kl = 0;
    $scope.hashId = function (id_movie) {
        this.ld = kl;
        kl++;
        console.log(this.ld);
    }
```

In view html:

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in data">
    <li><a ng-init='hashId()' target='_blank' href='myHref'>{{ld}}+{{x}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I would like to number these links by function hashId();
in console it's working, but in view, I see only one number for each link, the scope is overwritten last value. 
How to fix that ?

Comment: The sentence makes no sense: "and I want everyone to another link was another number from function hashId()". I get english may not be your first language, but you'll need somebody to help you clarify that.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `...> hashId: {{ld}} link: {{x}} </a>`

Comment: You can do `<a ng-init='x.Id = $index' target='_blank' href='myHref'>{{x.ld}}+{{x}}</a></li>`

Comment: this is not a good use for `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

Take that variabe to scope, as $scope.kl=0; then further in function use $scope.kl++;.

Answer (score 0):

`ld` will refer to the same variable. That's why you are seeing the last value.

You can instead use `$index` if that function is only going to increment:

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in data">
    <li><a target='_blank' href='myHref'>{{$index}}+{{x}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the hash and set it as a 'local' loop variable:

```
var kl = 0;
$scope.hashId = function (id_movie) {
    return kl++;
}

<ul ng-repeat="x in data" ng-init="id = hashId()">
    <li><a target='_blank' href='myHref'>{{id}}+{{x}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to start by suggesting  to remove the argument "id_movie", which is never used. 
To solve your problem in a more elegante way, simply map your array in something more useful for your purpose:

```
$scope.newData = data.map(function(item, index){
    return { ld : index, x : item };
});
```

And then, perform ng-repeat on newData.
Also: please, never ever ever ever use ng-init at all. Try to better understand how angular compiles its code and put all the non-rendering-related logic in your controller.